# Connection String - Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, connection-string

I need to connect an Oracle server with C#.
Here is the parameters for the string.

server : dbs.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr
port : 1521
sid : ORAVT

What is the connection string for these?I tried many ways to connect but i could not handle it.By the way I used ODP.NET.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: I tried this one but did not worked.

string oraDB = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbs.hacettepe.edu.tr)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORAVT)));User Id=********;Password=*******";

Comment: Another useful link: https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web.config

```
    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbs.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORAVT))); User Id=YOUR_USER_HERE; Password=YOUR_PASS_HERE;"/>
        </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

clsConn.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
    namespace Data
    {
       public class Data
        {
            public  OracleConnection GetConnection()
            {
                string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();

                return new OracleConnection(connection);
            }


            public DataTable ExecuteCmd()
            {
                OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection();
                OracleCommand dbCommand = cn.CreateCommand();
                DataTable oDt = new DataTable();

                cn = GetConnection();

                dbCommand.CommandText = "pckClient.spr_Client";
                dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                try
                {
                    dbCommand.Connection = cn;

                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("cCursorData", 
                    OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));

                    OracleDataAdapter oDa = new OracleDataAdapter(dbCommand);

                    oDa.Fill(oDt);

                    return oDt;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                    dbCommand.Dispose();
                    cn.Dispose();
                    throw ex;

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                    dbCommand.Dispose();
                    cn.Dispose();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```